# Deleting old release branches on build pipeline (Jenkins)

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-delivery

We are using Jenkins build pipeline plugin. And our continuous delivery strategy is simply like that;

1. Team pushes code, Jenkins initial job triggered....
2. A new release branch created.
3. if packaging and unit testing are successful. then
4. Push release branch to github otherwise delete locally created branch.
5. Artifacts archived and ....
6. ....

My reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McTZtyb9M38

As it is seen on step 4 every job triggers creates new branch and it causes to occur a branch pollution on our SCM.

How can i remove old branches from SCM (Github) i want to keep at least 5 newest branches on github.

Note : We do not deploy every build to production.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround solution may be like this;

as a post-build action;

```
#!/bin/sh
a=0
release=$2
until_build=`expr $1 - 5`
until [ ! $a -lt $until_build ]
do
  exists=`git show-ref release-"$release".$a`

  if [ -n "$exists" ]; then
    git branch -D tag-release-"$release".$a
    git push origin --delete release-"$release".$a
  fi
  a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```